# Undefined characters replacing text ("ti", "fb" for example) in Apache Tika output

Tags: pdfbox, apache-tika

I'm trying to parse a document using Apache Tika that unfortunately replaces some character sequences - "ti", "fb" for example - with the an unknown Unicode symbol. I don't see a way to manage this using Tika itself, as the replacement character seems to be coming from PDFBox.

I also noticed that the character sequences in question are not part of the GlyphList. Would it be possible to add the sequences and a mapping to the GlyphList to get the expected output? I'm using Tika 1.21 with PDFBox 2.0.15.

Comment: Those appear to be ligatures

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348632/handle-ligatures-in-apache-tika

Comment: Yes, they do appear to be ligatures or some other diglyphs; however, these particular combinations do not get handled by default. Others, such as "ff", seem to be known to PDFBox.

Comment: What happens if you copy paste from Adobe Reader?

Comment: Using the evince reader, I have the word "interesting" in the .pdf. I can find "interes". It cannot find "interest".

Comment: Same with Adobe Acrobat. No "t" is found in the string.

Comment: Then it is your PDF that is to blame: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#text-extraction

Comment: Ok. So are you confident that there is nothing that can be done to fix or handle the situation by configuring PDFBox or lower-level libraries?

Comment: Yes. It might be possible to fix that PDF itself. But that would be a lot of work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485920/how-to-add-unicode-in-truetype0font-on-pdfbox-2-0-0/39644941